# ¿Cómo evitar la redirección al error 404 al acceder a rutas declaradas con app.Map en .NET 7 sin intercalar los middlewares?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, middleware

Estoy haciendo pruebas con los middlewares en .NET 7 para contemplar los accesos a rutas inexistentes y así devolver un código 404.

Contexto:
Tengo varios middlewares que usan app:Map, como el caso de:

```
Test -> app.Map("/Test", app=>{app.UseMiddleware<MiMiddle>();});
```

Problema:

Si quiero acceder a un path de un controlador, puedo accederlo sin problemas, pero si escribo /Test me deriva a la página 404.

Pregunta:

¿Cómo puedo lograr que detecte los paths declarados mediante map sin intercalar los middlewares?, es decir, sin poner primero el map y luego el DefaultPageMiddleware.

Código de **Program.cs**

```
app.UseMiddleware<DefaultPageMiddleware>();
app.Map("/Test", app =>
{
    app.UseMiddleware<TestMiddleware>();
});

app.MapControllers();
```

Código de **DefaultPageMiddleware.cs**

```
 public class DefaultPageMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public DefaultPageMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>() == null || context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>().Endpoint == null)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/404.html");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            return _next(context);
            

        }
    }
```

Código de **TestMiddleware.cs**

```
public class TestMiddleware 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }


    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.WriteAsync("derify example");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class NotFoundMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public NotFoundMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
        {
            // Vamos manejando el 404 en esta línea:
            context.Response.Redirect("/error/404");
            // En teoría deberías colocar alguna ruta donde mostrar ese flamente 404. 
        }
    }
}
```

Y en el `program.cs`

```
app.UseMiddleware<NotFoundMiddleware>();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
```

Ojo que el orden es extremadamente importante en los middleware.

Comment: Claro, estamos preguntando debajo del await, lo que fue mi primer solución y es hasta ahora la mas prolija. Se ejecuta toda la cadena de responsabilidad en _next y abajo lo valido. Eso puedo hacerlo colocando el if de mi código debajo del await. Para el 404 uso el archivo estático 404.html en wwwroot.

Comment: No es exactamente la solución que busco, pero es lo que más se acerca a mi objetivo.

Answer (score 0):

Es hasta ahora (y similar a lo que dijo @fredyfx) la mejor solución que he intentado.

Colocar esta validación, debajo del _next ya que ese next es la ejecucion de toda la cadena de responsabilidad. Donde no matchee, saltaría todo derivando a 404.html, mi archivo estático en wwwroot.

```
public class DefaultPageMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public DefaultPageMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            

            await _next(context);

            if (context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>() == null || context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>().Endpoint == null)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/404.html");
                
            }

        }
    }
```